# Show the dictionary key in django template

Tags: python, django, templates, dictionary, key

Im wondering how i could show the dictionary key itself in a django template

Example dictionary:

```
resources = {'coin': coin, 'grain': grain, 'iron': iron, 'stone': stone, 'wood': wood,}
```

Template

```
<b>Coin: </b>{{ upgrade.coin }}
```

Were i want to use the dictionary key (+some html) instead of the hard coded "Coin:"

Can anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`for`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for) tag with [`dict.items`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#dict.items) if you want to print all key/value pairs:

```
{% for key, value in resources.items %}
    <b>{{ key }}: </b>{{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 3):

In your views, you can pass to render the whole dictionary and iterate over it in your template.

 **views.py**

```
def home(request):
    resources = {'coin': coin, 'grain': grain, 'iron': iron, 'stone': stone, 'wood': wood,}
    return render(request, "home.html", {'r':resources})
```

**home.html**

```
{% for key,value in r.items %}
    {{ key }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks, in view i was already using render, didn't realize you could do it with key + value in the for loop, thought you only could use the value