# Regroup data from model in Django views

Tags: django

I have a model with data like the following:

```
Name    Value    Date
pop1    15       2021-01-19
pup1    2        2021-01-18
pep1    25       2021-01-18
pop2    9        2021-01-17
pap1    1        2021-01-16
pep2    26       2021-01-16
pep3    4        2021-01-16
```

If i do `data = myModel.objects.all()` I obtain all the data in the normal structure, but what I want is obtain it grouped by date. Can this goal be achieved directly?

I ask this because I know how to filter using `myModel.objects.filter()` or order the data using `myModel.objects.order_by()`. Then, exists something like `myModel.objects.regroup('date')`?

**EDIT:**

The desired output is something like:

```
date:2021-01-19 >> [[name:pop1, value:15]]
date:2021-01-19 >> [[name:pup1, value:2],[name:pep1, value:25]]
date:2021-01-17 >> [[name:pop2, value:9]]
date:2021-01-16 >> [[name:pap1, value:1],[name:pep2, value:26],[name:pep3, value:4]]
```

Basically an object with the data regrouped by date.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please could you explain what your desired output would be?

Comment: Do you want to group the Values column together by Date?

Comment: Edited with the desired output! :)

Comment: you can use myModel.objects.all() and then process you dict tp get the desired output

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django GROUP BY field value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45163299/django-group-by-field-value)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django group by dates and SUM values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18099697/django-group-by-dates-and-sum-values)

Answer (score 2):

you can use this :

```
data=myModel.objects.all()
new_data={}
for e in data :
  
  if e.value('date') not in new_data :
    new_data[e.value('date')]=[e]
  else :
    new_data[e.value('date')].append(e)
print(new_data)
```

Comment: I tried this yesterday but appears this error `TypeError: 'myModel' object is not subscriptable`.

Comment: can u try my latest modifications

Comment: Finally I serialized the data from model before the loop for

Answer (score -1):

Based on the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45163299/django-group-by-field-value/45164792) and the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20956687/show-the-dictionary-key-in-django-template) you should be able to change your view as follows:

```
dates_list = MyModel.objects.values_list(
    'date', flat=True
).distinct()

group_by_date = {}
for date in dates_list:
    group_by_date[date] = MyModel.objects.filter(date=date)
```

then in your template:

```
{% for date, items in group_by_date %}
    date: {{ date }} >>

    {% for item in items %}
      [ name: {{ item.name }}, value: {{ item.value }} ]
    {% endfor %}

    <br />
{% endfor %
```

(Obviously you'll want to use more HTML tags to format the output in a more pleasing way!)